# Add timestamp to output log file before each object

Tags: powershell, timestamp, delete-file

I have a powershell script which deletes files and folders older than 180 days, and I would like to add date and time of deletion in the log file before each object. Is that possible?

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)
$path = "D:\RAZMJENA DOKUMENATA"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | out-file d:\Delete_script\deleted_files_log.txt -append 

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose 4>&1 | out-file d:\Delete_script\deleted_files_log.txt -append 

#Delete remaining empty folders older than 180 days.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse | Where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($limit) -and (gci $_.fullName).count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | out-file d:\Delete_script\deleted_files_log.txt -append
```

Comment: As aside, change `(Get-Date).AddDays($limit)` in the last line to `$limit`, as $limit is already the date to check against.

Comment: Dear Theo, thank you for the comment. I have corrected the last line as per your instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in you code with add foreachloop

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1|foreach{($_.Message).Tostring()+" "+((Get-Date).DateTime).ToString()} | out-file d:\Delete_script\deleted_files_log.txt -append
```

Comment: Dear Vad, thank you for your answer. It is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add the current date to every line. For the better understanding I would assign a temporary variable. You can do this with every line of code:

```
$tmp = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1 
$date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" #Format the Date
"$date --> $tmp" | out-file d:\Delete_script\deleted_files_log.txt -append #Append to logfile
```

---

Or even better, create a function that you can call everytime you want to log:

```
function logToFile($tmp){
      $date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" #Format the Date
      "$date --> $tmp" | out-file d:\Delete_script\deleted_files_log.txt -append 
}
```

Then you can call it whenever you want:

```
$tmp = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1 
logToFile $tmp
```

If you want to have another format of the date you can get more informations on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7

Comment: Dear Nicicalu, thank you for your response.
It was not exactly what i was looking for, but it is good to know how to use functions in powershell.

Comment: Oh okay, after I read the other answer I found out what your goal was.